# What do we mean when we say the Expected Value E[X] is linear?

Tags: probability

I know that $E[2-X]$ for instance is equal to: $2 - E[X]$. And it makes perfect sense to me, because $f(x)=x$ is linear.

However, $E[X^2]$ is equal to $\sum_{j=1}^n$ $x^2f(x)$, and $f(x) = x^2 $ is quadratic.

What do we mean by linear here, because I suspect it carries a different meaning.

Comment: but f(x) can be equal to x^3 right? what do you mean by the integral is linear?

Comment: Notice that $E[X^2] \neq E[X]^2$; in general $E[f(X)]\neq f(E[X])$. One of the few cases in which this last equality holds is when $f$ is linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is meant is that if $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are random variables, independent or not, and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are constants, then
$$E(a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n)=a_1E(X_1)+a_2E(X_2)+\cdots +a_nE(X_n).$$

So the expectation of a *linear combination* of random variables is easy to compute if we know the individual expectations. This is an extremely useful fact.

Let us consider your example $2-X$. Let $X_1$ be the random variable $2$. Kind of a boring random variable, but technically a perfectly legitimate one. Let $X_2=X$. Then
$$2-X=X_1+(-1)X_2.$$
Note that $E(X_1)=2$. So by the general linearity rule stated above, we have 
$$E(2-X)=E(X_1)+(-1)E(X_2)=2-E(X).$$

Comment: my real question was is this true: E[2-X] is equal to: 2 - E[X]? But I knew I would get a lot of thumbs down, so I asked the question indirectly. Sorry, for that.

Comment: Your example $2$ -$X$ is a special case, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: I thought E[2-X] may be equal to the sum of 1 to n of (2-x)f(x), but after reading the wikipedia article, i realized it probably isn't the case.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying you are a great contributor to this site.

Comment: If you have a *discrete* random variable, that takes on values $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$, then the expectation of $2-X$ really is $\sum_1^n (2-x_n)p_n$. So for this particular case what you said is right.